# Validation method called for defaults attrib on Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Since I've upgrade Backbone from 0.9.2 to 0.9.9, I'm getting some error.

When I instance a new model with hash default values. The validate method is call in order to validate these values and failed.

Basically I wanna set the contactModel with new message, but this message should be different than the default one. This is why the validation failed at the instance of this model.
This was working fine with backbone 0.9.2 as the validation method wasn't called at the instance.

Does someone can explain what is wrong with this ?

This is my BackboneModel :

```
class ContactModel extends Backbone.Model

    defaults :

        message : 'Initial message'


    validate : ( attrs_ ) =>

        if attrs_.message.toString() is @.defaults.message.toString()

            return 'Same message'

        if attrs_.message.length < 55

            return 'Your message is too short buddy'


    sync : =>

         #Custom Sync implementation
```

This is my BackboneView :

```
class ContactPageView extends AbstractView

    id          : 'contact-page'
    template    : null
    model       : null

    events : 

        'keypress #contactTextArea'     : 'onKeyPress'
        'submit #contactForm'           : 'submit'

    init : ->

        @model = new ContactModel()

        console.log @model.get 'message'

        #Print "undefined"


        @model.bind "success", @success, this

        @model.bind "error", @error, this

        @template = _.template $( '#template_page_contact' ).html()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Backbone 0.9.9 the semantics of model validation were changed so that validation should make sure that the model can **never** be in an invalid state, not even when the model is initialized. With this change the model instantiation will fail, because of the rule `attrs_.message.toString() is @.defaults.message.toString()`, and there is no way to get around it.

**However**, the change has later been rolled back, and the validation has been relaxed to allow invalid states up until saving the model. I presume this will be available in the next Backbone release, but for the time being there is no publicly available version with this change. [This GitHub issue page](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/issues/1961) discusses why the change was made for 0.9.9, and how it has been changed for the next version.

In the meantime you can either change your validation logic, go back to an earlier released version, or use the [unreleased master version](https://raw.github.com/documentcloud/backbone/master/backbone.js) at your own risk.